# Changing base classes (__bases__) once an instance is created. isinstance() manipulation. Python 2.7

Tags: python

I am looking to see if there is a good way to create a wrapping object.

```
class Thing_A(object):pass

class Thing_B(object):pass

class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
```

I am looking for a solution I can write in Wrapper class (or potentially a metaclass of Wrapper) so the following code is accurate. I don't have ability to change Thing_A or Thing_B classes in my real world scenario.

```
a_thing = Thing_A()
b_thing = Thing_B()
wrapper_a = Wrapper(a_thing)
wrapper_b = Wrapper(b_thing)

isinstance(wrapper_a, Thing_A) #needs to returns True
isinstance(wrapper_b, Thing_B) #needs to returns True
isinstance(wrapper_a, Thing_B) #needs to returns False
isinstance(wrapper_a, Wrapper) #needs to returns True
isinstance(wrapper_b, Wrapper) #needs to returns True
```

I tried looking at `__new__`, metaclasses and type class creation but I am not getting the result I want. If there is a better way to go at this without directly subclassing Thing_A or Thing_B please let me know. I also found that `__instancecheck__` but because I can't change Thing_A class or Thing_B class, I can't use it.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: If you want to see it done, I've written code that actually does this before (as a component in a system used in production at a former employer). See https://web.dyfis.net/bzr/isg_state_machine_framework/ -- the directory looks empty over a standard web browser but can be checked out with [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) for the source tree. Metaclasses were indeed a component of that solution.

Comment: Have you tried 'forwarding' the call of the first 2 examples to the original class in `self.thing`?  So you'd do something like `return isinstance(instance, self.thing)` to pass it to the wrapped class

Answer (score 1):

Do your best to look for other solutions. This kind of thing is prone to a lot of weird bugs, and it's going to be even more of an arcane mess to debug than it will be to write.

That said, if you really want to give yourself this maintenance nightmare, then the way to do it is to lie about `__class__`:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
    @property
    def __class__(self):
        return self.thing.__class__
```

[Ideone demo.](https://ideone.com/bmfSr2)

This only handles `isinstance`; if you want to forward attribute lookup to `self.thing`, you'll need to implement a forwarding `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`, and if you want magic methods to work, you're going to have to separately define forwarding implementations of every magic method you want to forward to `self.thing`.

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid this and find a different type of design pattern instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by this:

> I also found that `__instancecheck__` is possible to use for the last two `isinstance` checks but not the first two.

For the last two, you don't need to do anything. The default `type.__instancecheck__` is already going to return `True`, because your objects really are `Wrapper` instances.

For the first two, it certainly is possible. Obviously it depends on how you implement the [`__instancecheck__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#class.__instancecheck__), but any option you pick will work here, as long as you make it look at something on the instance.

---

Rather than hardcode something that looks at `self.thing`, let's write something more general: a protocol where any object can declare, dynamically, that it wants to be an instance of `Thing_A` or `Thing_B` by just adding it to some iterable called `self._fakebases`. So, `isinstance(thing, Thing_B)` will be true if `Thing_B` is in `type(thing).__bases__` (the usual rule) *or* in `thing._fakebases` (the rule you want to add):

```
class Fakey(type):
    def __instancecheck__(self, inst):
        if super().__instancecheck__(inst):
            return True
        try:
            if self in inst._fake_bases:
                return True
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return False

class Thing_A(metaclass=Fakey): pass

class Thing_B(metaclass=Fakey): pass
```

Now, `wrapper` can support that protocol by setting `_fake_bases`:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
        self._fake_bases = {type(thing)}
```

… or, maybe even better, use a `property`:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
    @property
    def _fake_bases(self):
        return {type(self.thing)}
```

Notice that `Wrapper` doesn't have to use the `Fakey` metaclass, because the default `__instancecheck__` rules work fine with `Wrapper` as the class; it's `Thing_A` and `Thing_B` where you want different behavior.

And here's that different behavior:

```
>>> a_thing = Thing_A()
>>> b_thing = Thing_B()
>>> wrapper_a = Wrapper(a_thing)
>>> wrapper_b = Wrapper(b_thing)
>>> isinstance(wrapper_a, Thing_A) #needs to returns True
True
>>> isinstance(wrapper_b, Thing_B) #needs to returns True
True
>>> isinstance(wrapper_a, Thing_B) #needs to returns False
False
>>> isinstance(wrapper_a, Wrapper) #needs to returns True
True
>>> isinstance(wrapper_b, Wrapper) #needs to returns True
True
```

Comment: ok the only problem that I have with this solution is that in the actual problem. I can't change the classes Thing_A and Thing_B and I already have the instances (I am not calling the constructors.).

Comment: You are correct as written the last two isinstance checks work. I goofed, they didn't work with my attempt locally with changing __new__ behavior.

Comment: @JasonJones Well, you _have_ to be able to change `Thing_A` and `Thing_B`. If you can't edit their code, or monkeypatch them, or replace them with wrapper classes around the real classes, then you can't hook their instance checks. (Well, I suppose you could wrap up the `isinstance` function instead, but that feels even uglier.)

Comment: @JasonJones As for already having the wrapper objects and not calling the constructors, that part is trivial. If you don't understand how to set or modify the instance attribute `_fake_bases` on an existing object, you really shouldn't be coming anywhere near this kind of code.

Comment: I have not problem adding/modifying ._fake_bases on an object. The problem is I can't change Thing_A or Thing_B classes.  I can/could overwrite the class __metaclass__but since one already exists, I don't know ramifications of changing it to Fakey type. I don't know how safe that solution would be.